# How LR parser works with grammar containing epsilon productions

Tags: formal-grammars, compilers

In Dragon book  for compiler design there is this example of SDT in Example 5.16

---

1. $L\rightarrow En$
2. $E\rightarrow \{ print (' +') ; \} \space E_1 + T$
3. $E\rightarrow T$
4. $T\rightarrow \{ print (' *' ) ; \} \space T_1 * F$
5. $T\rightarrow F$
6. $F\rightarrow ( E )$
7. $F\rightarrow digit \space \{ print ( digit . lexval) ; \}$

---

and then it writes

> Unfortunately, it is impossible to implement this SDT during either top­
> down or bottom-up parsing, because the parser would have to perform critical
> actions, like printing instances of * or +, long before it knows whether these
> symbols will appear in its input.
> Using marker nonterminals $M2$ and $M4$ for the actions in productions 2
> and 4, respectively, on input **3**, a shift-reduce parser ( see Section 4.5.3) has
> conflicts between reducing by $M2 \rightarrow \epsilon$, reducing by $M4 \rightarrow \epsilon$, and shifting the
> digit.

Definition of marker:

> SDT's that can be implemented during parsing can be characterized by in­
> troducing distinct marker nonterminals in place of each embedded action; each
> marker $M$ has only one production, $M  \rightarrow  \epsilon$. If the grammar with marker non­
> terminals can be parsed by a given method, then the SDT can be implemented
> during parsing.

But I don't see how such conflicts could occur on an input "3". Should not the LR(0) automaton
always reduce by $M_2\rightarrow \epsilon$ on a lookahead that is $digit$ instead of shifting $digit$ to stack. So there would never be shift/reduce conflict. explain please.

---

Edit:
- 
Suppose I have a Grammar, $G'$ with following productions.
$A\rightarrow M B$
$B\rightarrow b$
$M\rightarrow \epsilon$

then the LR(0) itemset will be as follows,

$I_0:$

0. $S\rightarrow .A$
1. $A\rightarrow .MB$
2. $B\rightarrow .b$
3. $M\rightarrow .$

Now since on $b \in follow(M)$, on input "b", we could either shift it to stack and move to state having item $[B\rightarrow b.]$ or reduce by production 3. So it is a Shift/reduce conflict.

Comment: The state $E\to\bullet M_2 E + T$ must also include $E\to\bullet  T$ and therefore $T\to\bullet M_4 T * F$, $T\to\bullet  F$, $F\to\bullet  ( E )$ and $F\to\bullet  \text{digit}$. All but one of those are appropriate with 3 as the lookahead. Not all of those are compatible with reducing by production 2.

Comment: @rici I have made an edit to show what I understood from your comment. Is this correct.

Comment: no, that's not correct. If the only rule for $A$ is $A\to MB$ then rules for $B$ will not be in the item set closure, and there will be no conflict. That's quite different from the grammar in your original question, where there are two rules for $E$ which lead eventually to different actions. (There are also two rules for $F$, expanding the conflict.)  I suggest that you construct the LR(0) table by hand, concentrating on the item set closures. It won't take you long, and doing the work with pencil and paper helps understanding more than any reading.